# My basement perimeter tile drains into my sump pump pit and floods my basement

Tags: basement

My basement perimeter tile drains into my sump pump pit and floods my basement. I struggle to pump water out on my small property. there is a field tile on my property however it has been clogged for years. I don't know who to call.[image]

Tiles coming into pit are from the perimeter of my basement walls (I guess). Sump pump used to discharge to a field tile which runs across my property. We know this to be clogged. Now I discharge on top of the ground, as far from the house as I can. In dry summer months I discharge into my septic system.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture or two of the tile and pit to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the picture, but it still isn't clear what's going on here. What drains into the sump pump? Why won't the sump pump keep your basement dry? Where's the pump outlet? Is the problem more than just the pump doesn't go to a good place for the water to drain?